# How to make a connection from mobile to pc in flutter

Tags: android, windows, flutter

So my problem is I want to make an app that can connect to the desktop and communicate with the device in a real production app.... not through usb debugging. In short an app that will connect to a pc and communicate with it either through usb or bluetooth or websocket ports. But I want to do this in a production app, where the user won't enable usb debugging. Kinda like iot

Is there any way i can do so

Comment: Very broad question. Be more precisely what do you mean by `communicate`, `a production app`

Comment: Basically i want to move the cursor on my laptop using my phone